# How to resume pause button- Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to pause the scene and I can pause it with this code but how do I resume it when I click the same button?

```
@property (SK_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY, getter = isPaused) BOOL paused;


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *pause = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"pause"];

        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if([pause containsPoint:location])
        {
            self.scene.view.paused = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried variably changing the paused property based on its current state?

Comment: this will toggle it: self.scene.view.paused = !self.scene.view.paused;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.scene.view.paused = !self.scene.view.paused;
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for looking into this. This does resume the scene but there is a problem. For example. If I had a ball jumping and when  resumed  that ball would start moving again but from a different location not from where that ball  was paused. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @user3725724 Check your code, maybe there is something that moves ball's location while paused.